# Need to count records in rdl with page breaks

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have a report that uses page breaks to show 1 record per page. I need to get a count of the records (outside of looking at the page number) and show it at the bottom of my table on each page. The page break is seperating my data groupings making the count always return 1.

The page break is on a group using the expression `=Ceiling(Rownumber(Nothing)/1)`

I am attempting to get the count of records by counting the occurences of the identifier field.

Is this even possible or am I just going about the solution wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a placeholder with the following expression `=CountRows("YourDataSet")`

This will count all of the rows that your data set returns.